# Angular library on ng build files are not included on dist folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9, angular-library

I have a library create with angular 9 with a project structure like below

[image: project description]

When I build the library `ng build falcon-core` the view-models files are not included in the dist folder

[image]

I didn't find any settings related to the files structure in the `tsconfig.lib.ts`

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

why the files are not included in the dist folder after build.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, but I was not aware of

Need to update the public-api.ts file to expose the files

```
export * from './lib/view-models/imeta';
export * from './lib/view-models/component-type-enum';
```

Comment: Something to add from my very recent experience...if the files are use in the lib code they are included in the "bundle" and can be referenced in the consuming app but if said classes, services etc were not put in the public-api.ts then you eventually get a build error saying as much!